# how to create a dataframe using groupy such that the grouping criteria is contained in the data

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to create a 2D dataframe about coronavirus such that it contains a column containing countries and another one containing number of deaths. the csv file that I am using is date oriented so for some days the number of deaths is 0 so I decided to group them by Country and sum them up. yet it returned a dataframe with 1 column only. but when I write it to a csv file it creates 2 columns.
here is my code:

```
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
covid_data = pd.read_csv('countries-aggregated.csv')
bar_data = pd.DataFrame(covid_data.groupby('Country')['Deaths'].sum())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to give you a perfect answer without the dataset, however, groupby will set your key as index, thus returning a Series. You can pass `as_index=False`:

```
bar_data = covid_data.groupby('Country', as_index=False)['Deaths'].sum()
```

Or, if you have only one column in the DataFrame to aggregate:

```
bar_data = covid_data.groupby('Country', as_index=False).sum()
```